# how to create a hyper-link in iReport?

Tags: ireport

I'm using iReport-3.7.6 
I have created a sample_Report1 with one parameter as (Project_name) and
I have created the Sample_Report2 with one parameter as (Employee_No)
Now I want to create a hyper-link in Sample_Report1 to Sample_Report2.
(pass the employee_no as a parameter to Sample_Report2 from Sample_Report1 using hyper-link)

Comment: See the Example in JasperServer "Reports -> Samples -> Employee List" Like wise I want to create my Report

Answer (score 3):

rclick on the text field > link parameter

hyperlink target: Self
hyperlink type: ReportExecution

A.  add "link parameter name" = uri (well in my repository setup this is what I use)
then Value Expression is the URL enclosed in " "

B. Click on add again "parameter name" value will be the field parameter

when you click mouse over on the link it should be like this

```
www.yoursite.com/reports/executeReports.jsp?uri=/path/report/yearend&year=2010
```

this is your URI = "uri=/path/report/yearend"
this is your parameter = "year=2010"

hope this helps...